# How to zip a directory without zipping the parents directories?

Tags: command-line

I have a directory called Klox with whats of files and images.

Klox is located in `~/Projects/Klox`

When I use `zip -r Klox.zip ~/Projects/Klox` the archive is containing all the directories until reaching Klox. `/home/vk/projects/Klox`

I want the zip file to contain only the Klox folder. So people don't have to open home folder, then open vk folder then open projects and finally open Klox

Comment: Try `zip -r Klox.zip ~/Projects/Klox/*`

Comment: I've tried that it's not working, I don't know why, I red that  `/*` should work but...

Comment: `cd ~/Projects/; zip -r ~/Klox.zip Klox/`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `zip` utility stores paths relative to the current working directory, so you have to use `cd` or `pushd`/`popd` to go to `~/Projects` first:

```
cd ~/Projects
zip -r Klox.zip Klox
```

or when you want to return to the original working directory afterwards:

```
pushd ~/Projects
zip -r Klox.zip Klox
popd
```